# Get the filename of the excel file you are importing into power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, filenames

How do I get the filename of the excel file I am importing into power bi?

For example if I am importing C:/Path/abc.xlsx, how do I get "C:/Path/abc.xlsx" as a variable.
Excel had the method ActiveWorkbook.Name. What is that in power bi?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just saw a solution to that. Maybe [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-get-excel-workbook-name-and-sheet-name/td-p/1000787) can help you